# mysql 5.6.10 fulltext search not working with #

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mariadb

With **mysql 5.6.10** , following MATCH condition in WHERE clause gives no result , however there is 1 record in table with col1 having "#xyz". There is also a fulltext index on individual fields i.e col1 and col2 as well as  on combination of all these fields i.e (col1 and col2)

```
AND MATCH(t1.col1, t1.col2) against('#xyz' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

innodb_ft_min_token_size is set to 1

**But with mysql 5.6.28 / Mariadb 10.1.9, above query works and gives results with identical settings**

sql_mode is set in both places to STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

When I remove # it works however with also 5.6.10. Is there any bug with 5.6.10 w.r.t full text search and # character ?

I have tried dropping and recreating index without success.

Comment: When you say "MySQL 5.6.10," are you really talking about Aurora?  If you are, you need to say so, because even though that's the version number that Aurora *reports* as its version, it's not the same thing.

Comment: I just did version check again and it says - Server version: 5.6.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL) that is installed on ubuntu 14.04